# Pass Apex method parameter value with Visualforce 'apex:actionSupport'

Tags: apex-code, visualforce

Can anyone please tell me how can I pass Apex method parameter value with Visualforce 'apex:actionSupport'.

Apex code:

```
public void renderField(String sampleType) { }
```

Visualforce code:

```
<apex:inputField id="sampleType" value="{!job.Sample_Type__c}">   
  <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!renderField(?)}" rerender="otherSampleType"/>       
</apex:inputField>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Action methods don't support passing arguments like that. Instead, you just have to bind VF components to controller properties. In your case, it looks like you may be wanting to get the value of the "sampleType" inputField. If so, you just need a controller property that holds a reference to the "Job". Assuming the type is Job__c, this declaration on the controller would work:

```
public Job__c Job { get; set; }
```

When your actionSupport fires, `Job.Sample_Type__c` will be populated from the inputField.

Comment: Hi Jeremy Ross! Thanks a lot. Yes I have done that way. Can you please tell me what is the usage of 'apex:param' as, 
<apex:actionSupport event="onmouseover" rerender="detail">
<apex:param name="cid" value="{!contact.id}"/>
</apex:actionSupport>

Comment: This probably results in a URL parameter of "cid". You can try accessing it in the controller with `String cid = ApexPages.CurrentPage.getParameters().get('cid');`

Comment: Hi Jeremy Ross! Thanks a lot. Have a nice time!